# Why is the __cmp__ of a tuple element used for the tuple itself when put into a Queue.PriorityQueue?

Tags: python, python-2.7, queue

If I do in `python` 2.7.10

```
import Queue

class Item(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "bla"

    def __cmp__(a, b):
        return cmp(a.name, b.name)

e_queue = Queue.PriorityQueue()
e_queue.put((1,2))
item = Item()
e_queue.put((1, item))
```

the second `put` fails with

```
...
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 136, in put
    self._put(item)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 225, in _put
    heappush(self.queue, item)
  File "tuple_nonsense.py", line 10, in __cmp__
    return cmp(a.name, b.name)
```

Apparently the `__cmp__` of `Item` is applied to the `tuple` in which it is contained. [The Queue docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) even suggest using tuples as items:

> A typical pattern for entries is a tuple in the form: (priority_number, data).)

So, what the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, [when you compare sequences, the elements in them are compared on by one](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types). So, when the tuples `(1, 2)` and `(1, item)` are compared, the first elements are the same. So the second elements are compared to determine which one is smaller. Since you have `2` and `item`, and `item` has `__cmp__` implemented, it calls that function.

You can confirm this with a simple `print` statement, like this

```
class Item(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "bla"

    def __cmp__(a, b):
        print a, b
        return cmp(a.name, b.name)
```

Here `a` will be the `item` object and `b` will be `2`. Since `2` doesn't have the `name` attribute, it fails with

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'name'